# Is SCHED_FIFO thread rescheduled to the end of a list after sleeping

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler, blocking

As the [sched(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) man page says:

> 2. When a blocked SCHED_FIFO thread becomes runnable, it will be inserted at the end of the list for its priority.

But officially there is no *blocked* state of a thread - there are only *Interruptible Sleep (S)* and *Uninterruptible Sleep (D)*.

Questions:

1. If a thread is sleeping on [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [clock_nanosleep(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html), is that the *Interruptible Sleep* (both can be woken up on a signal)? I assume probably yes for both.
2. After *Interruptible Sleep*, is the thread placed at the end of the scheduling list?
3. The same as 2. but for *Uninterruptible Sleep*?

I think that answer to all of the questions is "Yes" but I have to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either in a Runnable state or in the one of the Sleep states (i.e. blocked)

So you are right that the two syscalls can be interrupted by a signal, such that both are Interruptible sleep

Comment: Great, thank you for the confirmation!